# AWS LBR vs. CloudFront for uses allready located in closest region

Tags: legal

I have a domain name registered with Route 53 for a web app. The app will be used only by people in one country thus the closest region is chosen accordingly.

Since closest aws region for the app users is selected, will the advantages offered by either LBR or CloudFront be useful in this case, and if so, how? Thanks

Comment: Both LBR and CloudFront are services provided by AWS, thus hosting recommendations is NOT related to the question subject.

Comment: Looking into edge location gives you most of the answer. You have only 1 closest region server, then I don't think LBR will gonna help you. Cloudfront is helpful to serve and cache static content fast, but first compare your server location and cloudfront edge location, if both are closest or same, then you will not going to get benefits of cloudfront. For caching your static content you can do that directly on Amazon S3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already chosen the best possible region for your target customers then latency based routing will simply increase the cost of what you have already achieved. Additionally latency based routing is designed to work when you have servers in multiple availability zones or regions so as to route the user to the most appropriate availability zone based on the lowest latency from the end users location.

As for CloudFront this is a slightly different kettle of fish. CloudFront, being a content distribution network, has edge servers on a large number of different public and private network and while AWS does identify the location of most of its CloudFront edges this list does not necessarily include instances where an edge has been colocated at an ISP's network to bring the content as close to the end user as possible. It also allows to shift some load from your app servers to some specially designed static content servers which AWS keeps running fast. At this point the only way to answer your question is to ask yourself "Is the cost of using CloudFront going to be worth the decreased load on my servers?" The other thing to bear in mind is that by shifting static content to CloudFront you may find that overall load time is faster for your site not specifically due to server load, but rather due to parallell loading of static content due to the different domain being used for cloudfront (app.domain.com, cdn.domain.com).

Hope this helps.